# In OMNeT++/SimuLTE is it possible to reassign bands?

Tags: omnet++, lte

I have implemented a Device2Device-capable LTE scheduler for the `SimuLTE` framework for `OMNeT++`. It needs to reassign resource blocks. In typical LTE networks, each resource blocks is assigned to at most 1 node. With the advent of D2D, uplink resource blocks can be reassigned to D2D users.

The simulator knows both resource blocks and bands. A band is a logical collection of transmission frequencies. If `numBands == numRBs` then each band corresponds to one resource block.

So to try things out, I set `numRbs = 1 = numBands` and have two nodes. My scheduler simply assigns the first band to the first node, and then attempts to reassign the same band to the second node. The `SchedulingResult` tells me I should `TERMINATE` here - which seems like reassignment is not supported at all.

However, both nodes transmit UDP packets and if I run the simulation to the end, I find that both actually got to send out the same number of packets. Going through the logs I find that every 5th scheduling round (the number 5 might be specific to my setup), the second node still gets the `TERMINATE` answer, but is granted a resource block anyway. This seems to happen within the `eNodeB Main Loop`. How, why, what's going on? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that one of the two notions of bands and resource blocks are obsolete and likely to be removed in a later version. Users of the framework **should set numBands==numRBs!** The number of resource blocks is absolute, so this means that per band there's going to be one resource block available.

Note that band reassignment is not currently supported. Trying to do so will always end in the `TERMINATE answer` as described in the question, because there's a check that makes sure that the number of unassigned resource blocks is >0, which is not true if the band has already been assigned (and therefore the resource block linked to it).